# An abstract algebra teacher wanted to give his students a list of nine whole numbers that form a group under multiplication modulo 91.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

An abstract algebra teacher wanted to give his students a list of nine whole numbers that form a group under multiplication modulo 91.
$$\{1,9,16,22,53,74,79,81\}$$
He forgot one of the nine numbers. What was the forgotten number?
I'm comfused, help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing number is **29**. The mentioned group of order 9 is $\mathbb Z_3^2$, with 9 and 16 as generators:

```
 1 > 16 > 74 >
 v    v    v
 9 > 53 > 29 >
 v    v    v
81 > 22 > 79 >
 v    v    v
```